# Adding an item to an existent window

Tags: extjs

How can i add an item to an existent window? I tried win.add() but it does not seem to work. Why? This is my piece of code:

```
function combo_service(winTitle,desc,input_param) {

        /* parametri */
        param=input_param.split(","); /* della forma: param[0]="doc1:text", quindi da splittare di nuovo */

   /* cosi' non la creo più volte */
   win;

   if (!win)
    var win = new Ext.Window({
         //title:Ext.get('page-title').dom.innerHTML
        renderTo:Ext.getBody()
        ,iconCls:'icon-bulb'
        ,width:420
        ,height:240
        ,title:winTitle
        ,border:false
        ,layout:'fit'
        ,items:[{
            // form as the only item in window
             xtype:'form'
            ,labelWidth:60
                ,html:desc
            ,frame:true
            ,items:[{
                // textfield
                 fieldLabel:desc
                ,xtype:'textfield'
                ,anchor:'-18'
                }]
        }]
        });

win.add({
            // form as the only item in window
             xtype:'form'
            ,labelWidth:60
                ,html:desc
            ,frame:true
            ,items:[{
                // textfield
                 fieldLabel:desc
                ,xtype:'textfield'
                ,anchor:'-18'
                }]});

    win.show();


};
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
win;
```

declares win as global, then

```
var win = ...
```

redeclares it as a local var when creating the window.  Instead, `win` should be declared non-globally, but outside the scope of wherever this code lives (or passed into it as a function arg).  Then just remove the `win;` line and the `var` keyword and make sure all code is referencing the same variable.

Also, if the window is already rendered, then you add new components into it, you'll probably have to call `win.doLayout()` for the window layout to be refreshed.

Comment: thank you very much. This is the final code (for anyone who had my same problems): http://pastebin.com/v7ww7WJc